# Cant find -lgcc_s when compiling C-Code in an docker container

Tags: gcc, makefile, dockerfile, osdev

I am working on my own OS but when compiling I am getting the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:48: dist/x86_64/kernel.bin] Error 1
```

while having the compiler installed and set up.
I have attached my Makefile and my Dockerfile so maybe you see something that I could have missed here.

This is my Makefile:

```
# Define variables
TARGET_DIR = targets/x86_64
BUILD_DIR = build/x86_64
DIST_DIR = dist/x86_64

CC = gcc
CXX = g++
NASM = nasm

# Set the LIBRARY_PATH
LIBRARY_PATH := /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9:$(LIBRARY_PATH)

# Specify the location of libgcc_s
LDLIBS += -lgcc_s

# List of assembly source files
ASM_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/x86_64/boot/*.asm)

# List of object files
OBJECTS = $(patsubst src/x86_64/boot/%.asm,$(BUILD_DIR)/boot/%.o,$(ASM_SOURCES))

# List of C source files
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/x86_64/boot/*.c)
C_OBJECTS = $(patsubst src/x86_64/boot/%.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/boot/%.o,$(C_SOURCES))

# Kernel source files
KERNEL_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/kernel/*.c)
KERNEL_OBJECTS = $(patsubst src/kernel/%.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel/%.o,$(KERNEL_SOURCES))

# Compile C object files
$(BUILD_DIR)/boot/%.o: src/x86_64/boot/%.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c -I src/intf -ffreestanding $< -o $@

# Compile kernel object files
$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel/%.o: src/kernel/%.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c -I src/intf -ffreestanding $< -o $@

# Rule to assemble assembly source files to object files
$(BUILD_DIR)/boot/%.o: src/x86_64/boot/%.asm
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(NASM) -f elf64 $< -o $@

# Rule to link the kernel binary
$(DIST_DIR)/kernel.bin: $(OBJECTS) $(C_OBJECTS) $(KERNEL_OBJECTS)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -n -T $(TARGET_DIR)/linker.ld $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

# Rule to create the kernel ISO image
$(DIST_DIR)/kernel.iso: $(DIST_DIR)/kernel.bin $(TARGET_DIR)/iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    cp $< $(TARGET_DIR)/iso/boot/kernel.bin
    grub-mkrescue /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc -o $@ $(TARGET_DIR)/iso

# Build target for x86_64
build-x86_64: $(DIST_DIR)/kernel.iso

# Clean target
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
    rm -rf $(DIST_DIR)

.PHONY: build-x86_64 clean
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


RUN sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu.com/de.archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential


WORKDIR /root/env


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    apt-utils \
    gcc-9 \
    g++-9 \
    make \
    nasm \
    xorriso \
    grub-pc-bin \
    grub-common \
    wget \
    curl \
    git \
    gdb \
    libgcc-9-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


ENV PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"


VOLUME /root/env


ENV LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu


CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I have rewritten the Docker- and Makefile and checked the Filepaths which did not fix the issue.

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but on my Gentoo system `libgcc_s` isn't installed in a standard library location.  I'm also pretty sure `libgcc_s` is for the compiler's use, not general use when linking.  Why do you need it explicitly?

Comment: While testing I got an error message saying it couldnt find libgcc_s when I tried to run make. I removed the libgcc_s from the makefile and it still told me it couldnt find lgcc_s